# Reference Type Object is not getting updated , but returning updated object

Tags: c#

I am passing "a reference type" to the function "BY VAL" . In the Function I am trying to modify the reference type in foreach loop.

Then when it comes to the caller, 
object which I passed is not getting updated.
But returning updated object.

I have given the Example of this problem below.

Could someone assist me why it is happening like this by spending a few minutes?

The below are the methods GetStudents(), FilterStudents(),
classes, Student, Teacher, SSCClass,

SSCClass - Contains Teachers Array.
Teacher - Contains Students Array.

```
    public void GetStudents()
    {

        Student[] sscStudentsOne = new Student[] { new Student { V_SId = 1, V_SName = "Kumar" }, new Student { V_SId = 2, V_SName = "Varun" }, new Student { V_SId = 3, V_SName = "Murthy" } };

        Student[] sscStudentsTwo = new Student[] { new Student { V_SId = 4, V_SName = "Sathya" }, new Student { V_SId = 5, V_SName = "Krishna" }, new Student { V_SId = 6, V_SName = "Bindu" } };


        Teacher[] sscTeachers = new Teacher[] { new Teacher { V_tId = 1, V_tName = "Jyothi", V_Students = sscStudentsOne }, new Teacher { V_tId = 2, V_tName = "Srinivas", V_Students = sscStudentsTwo } };

        SSCClass objSSCClass = new SSCClass();
        objSSCClass.V_sscTeachers = sscTeachers;

        SSCClass objSSCClassFiltered =  FilterStudents(objSSCClass);
        // Problem :-
        // in objSSCClass Kumar is getting removed but Sathya from second teachere is not getting removed.
        // in objSSCClassFiltered  Kumar and Sathya are Getting removed as we did.
        // We need objSSCClass object to be updated successfully ..  as we can not return this to caller method in my project.

    }
    public SSCClass FilterStudents(SSCClass objSSCClasstobeFiltered)
    {

        foreach (Teacher item in objSSCClasstobeFiltered.V_sscTeachers)
        {

            // here a method will be called and does the below
            // removes Students based on some criteria
            // Say,
            // Remove Student Kumar  from first teacher.
            // Remove Student Sathya from second teacher

        }

        // after filtering Students return the SSC Class object

        return objSSCClasstobeFiltered;
    }

    public class Student
    {

        int v_sId;

        public int V_SId
        {
            get { return v_sId; }
            set { v_sId = value; }
        }

        string v_SName;

        public string V_SName
        {
            get { return v_SName; }
            set { v_SName = value; }
        }
    }

    public class Teacher
    {

        int v_tId;

        public int V_tId
        {
            get { return v_tId; }
            set { v_tId = value; }
        }


        string v_tName;

        public string V_tName
        {
            get { return v_tName; }
            set { v_tName = value; }
        }


        Student[] v_Students;

        public Student[] V_Students
        {
            get { return v_Students; }
            set { v_Students = value; }
        }
    }


    public class SSCClass
    {
        Teacher[] v_sscTeachers;

        public Teacher[] V_sscTeachers
        {
            get { return v_sscTeachers; }
            set { v_sscTeachers = value; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Post the code of the function with which you're having trouble with, because I, myself, don't quiet understand the core of the problem.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Can you add the actual code and not just comments , thanks.

Comment: Also add the code that removes the items

Comment: Hi
Thank you for your reply.
I am calling the function FilterStudents(objSSCClass) as below.

 SSCClass objSSCClassFiltered =  FilterStudents(objSSCClass);

Comment: Problem is , in FilterStudents, upto last statement object (objSSCClass ) is getting updated properly .

in the funnction I am removing some students from each teacher.
When it come to caller , for one teacher students are getting removed but for another teacher it is not getting removed.

i.e,
// in objSSCClass Kumar is getting removed but Sathya from second teachere is not getting removed.
// in objSSCClassFiltered  Kumar and Sathya are Getting removed as we did.
// We need objSSCClass object to be updated successfully ..  as we can not return this to caller method in my project.

Comment: objSSCClass is object type we passed to the function.

objSSCClassFiltered  is object returned from the Function

Answer (score 0):

You can't update `Foreach` Ref, make a new one and then update it:

```
Foreach (Student s in student_list)
{...
   S s2 = s;
     s2 = newval;
...}
```

Comment: "Modifying the reference type in foreach" sounds more like changing the inner state of the object, rather than the reference of the variable. Perhaps I'm wrong, but this doesn't seem to be related to OP's question.